# How many bytes does a tsrange field take in Postgres 13? (Column Tetris)

Tags: postgresql, range

I'm trying to find out the byte requirements for a `tsrange` field as I'm playing "column Tetris" on a large table.

I didn't find this spelled out in the manuals, so I took a stab at `pg_type`:

```
select typlen, typalign, typname 
  from pg_type where typname = 'tsrange' or typname = 'timestamp'
```

With these results:

```
typlen  typalign   typname
 8      d          timestamp
-1      d          tsrange
```

The docs explain that a `typealign` of `d` indicates "double alignment (8 bytes on many machines, but by no means all." and that a `typelen` of `-1` indcates "a 'varlena' type (one that has a length word).

If I reaad that right, then `tsrange` is variable length, and up to `8 + 8 + 8 = 24` (?) bytes? Is that right? In such a case I'd position it at the end/right of the table, with my other variable-length fields, like `text` or `citext`.

Does that sound correct? And, out of curiosity, why is it a variable length type?

I figure that I should flesh out my question with an example that shows what I'm after. Namely, figuring out where to position the column, amongst other columns, for optimal storage layout. Huge table, it might actually mater. I'm *guessing* that that order should be

```
fixed length types, from largest to smallest: uuid-bigint-integer, etc.
variable length types, with tsrange first
```

This is not quite how my "tetris" script is currently spitting out suggested order. The script makes some pointless suggestions about reordering columns wit equivalent type lengths and padding...that's not the issue. (It doesn't get in my way.) The issue is, where does a variable-length type with an 8-byte alignment belong with variable-length types with 4-byte alignment? At the start (left) or end (right)?

## Table Definition

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ascendco.edge CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ascendco.edge (
    id                           uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    inv_id                       uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    from_scan_at_facility_id     uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    from_associated_to_id        uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    to_associated_to_id          uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    from_web_user_id             uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    from_assembly_id             uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    from_scan_id                 uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    from_sterilizer_load_id      uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    from_facility_location_id    uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    from_facility_id             uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    from_washer_load_id          uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    from_scase_id                uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    from_clinic_id               uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    from_facility_department_id  uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    hsys_id                      uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    to_scan_id                   uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    to_scan_at_facility_id       uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    to_web_user_id               uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    to_facility_location_id      uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    to_sterilizer_load_id        uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    to_washer_load_id            uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    to_facility_id               uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    to_scase_id                  uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    to_clinic_id                 uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    to_facility_department_id    uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    to_assembly_id               uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    num_inst                     integer     NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    seconds                      integer     NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    from_node_dts                timestamp   NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    to_node_dts                  timestamp   NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    created_dts                  timestamp   NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    updated_dts                  timestamp   NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    from_to_range                tsrange     GENERATED ALWAYS AS (tsrange(from_node_dts, to_node_dts)) STORED,
    sequence_                    citext      NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    from_node                    citext      NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    to_node                      citext      NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    from_to_node                 citext      NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    from_associated_to           citext      NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    to_associated_to             citext      NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    from_user_name               citext      NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    source_                      citext      NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    is_fake                      citext      NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    to_user_name                 citext      NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,

CONSTRAINT edge_id_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY (id),

CONSTRAINT finishes_after_starts
    CHECK (from_node_dts <= to_node_dts) -- Make sure that we don't end up with *any* records with a start time later than the end time. = is fine.
);
```

## Column Tetris Function

```
/*
 Table_in is a 'regclass'. It's a way of avoiding SQL injection problems,
not that there is a chance of that here. (No dynamic SQL.) The really nice
part is that you can pass in table_name or schema_name.table_name this way
and either work magically.
*/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dba.column_tetris (table_in regclass)
    RETURNS table (
      column_name           text,
      type_name             text,
      type_align            text,
      alignment_description text,
      type_length           int2,
      suggestioned_position int8,
      current_position      int2
    )

AS $BODY$

   SELECT a.attname::text  AS column_name,
          t.typname::text  AS type_name,
          t.typalign::text AS type_align,

          CASE
             WHEN typalign = 'c' THEN 'char alignment, no alignment needed'
             WHEN typalign = 's' THEN 'short alignment, 2 bytes on most machines'
             WHEN typalign = 'i' THEN 'int alignment, 4 bytes on most machines'
             WHEN typalign = 'd' THEN 'double alignment, 8 bytes on many machines, but by no means all'
             ELSE 'Unexpected typalign ' || typalign
            END AS alignment_description,

          t.typlen   AS type_length,
          ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY t.typlen DESC,a.attname) as suggested_position,
          a.attnum   AS currrent_position

     FROM pg_class c
     JOIN pg_attribute a ON (a.attrelid = c.oid)
     JOIN pg_type t ON (t.oid = a.atttypid)

    WHERE c.relname = table_in::name AND
          a.attnum >= 0

 ORDER BY t.typlen DESC,a.attname;

$BODY$
    LANGUAGE sql;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION dba.column_tetris (regclass) IS '
/*
Adapted from this excellent blog post:
https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/on-rocks-and-sand/
*/';
```

## Tetris Results

```
+-----------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+------------------+
| column_name                 | type_name | type_align | alignment_description                                           | type_length | suggestioned_position | current_position |
+-----------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+------------------+
| from_assembly_id            | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 1                     | 7                |
| from_associated_to_id       | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 2                     | 4                |
| from_clinic_id              | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 3                     | 14               |
| from_facility_department_id | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 4                     | 15               |
| from_facility_id            | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 5                     | 11               |
| from_facility_location_id   | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 6                     | 10               |
| from_scan_at_facility_id    | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 7                     | 3                |
| from_scan_id                | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 8                     | 8                |
| from_scase_id               | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 9                     | 13               |
| from_sterilizer_load_id     | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 10                    | 9                |
| from_washer_load_id         | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 11                    | 12               |
| from_web_user_id            | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 12                    | 6                |
| hsys_id                     | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 13                    | 16               |
| id                          | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 14                    | 1                |
| inv_id                      | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 15                    | 2                |
| to_assembly_id              | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 16                    | 27               |
| to_associated_to_id         | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 17                    | 5                |
| to_clinic_id                | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 18                    | 25               |
| to_facility_department_id   | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 19                    | 26               |
| to_facility_id              | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 20                    | 23               |
| to_facility_location_id     | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 21                    | 20               |
| to_scan_at_facility_id      | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 22                    | 18               |
| to_scan_id                  | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 23                    | 17               |
| to_scase_id                 | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 24                    | 24               |
| to_sterilizer_load_id       | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 25                    | 21               |
| to_washer_load_id           | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 26                    | 22               |
| to_web_user_id              | uuid      | c          | char alignment, no alignment needed                             | 16          | 27                    | 19               |
| created_dts                 | timestamp | d          | double alignment, 8 bytes on many machines, but by no means all | 8           | 28                    | 32               |
| from_node_dts               | timestamp | d          | double alignment, 8 bytes on many machines, but by no means all | 8           | 29                    | 30               |
| to_node_dts                 | timestamp | d          | double alignment, 8 bytes on many machines, but by no means all | 8           | 30                    | 31               |
| updated_dts                 | timestamp | d          | double alignment, 8 bytes on many machines, but by no means all | 8           | 31                    | 33               |
| num_inst                    | int4      | i          | int alignment, 4 bytes on most machines                         | 4           | 32                    | 28               |
| seconds                     | int4      | i          | int alignment, 4 bytes on most machines                         | 4           | 33                    | 29               |
| from_associated_to          | citext    | i          | int alignment, 4 bytes on most machines                         | -1          | 34                    | 39               |
| from_node                   | citext    | i          | int alignment, 4 bytes on most machines                         | -1          | 35                    | 36               |
| from_to_node                | citext    | i          | int alignment, 4 bytes on most machines                         | -1          | 36                    | 38               |
| from_to_range               | tsrange   | d          | double alignment, 8 bytes on many machines, but by no means all | -1          | 37                    | 34               |
| from_user_name              | citext    | i          | int alignment, 4 bytes on most machines                         | -1          | 38                    | 41               |
| is_fake                     | citext    | i          | int alignment, 4 bytes on most machines                         | -1          | 39                    | 43               |
| sequence_                   | citext    | i          | int alignment, 4 bytes on most machines                         | -1          | 40                    | 35               |
| source_                     | citext    | i          | int alignment, 4 bytes on most machines                         | -1          | 41                    | 42               |
| to_associated_to            | citext    | i          | int alignment, 4 bytes on most machines                         | -1          | 42                    | 40               |
| to_node                     | citext    | i          | int alignment, 4 bytes on most machines                         | -1          | 43                    | 37               |
| to_user_name                | citext    | i          | int alignment, 4 bytes on most machines                         | -1          | 44                    | 44               |
+-----------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: `select pg_column_size(tsrange(localtimestamp, localtimestamp))` returns 9

Comment: `pg_column_size`, nice one, thanks! I just ran this on a table wit a `tsrange` and I'm getting lengths of 6 and 22. `with check_it as ( select pg_column_size(from_to_range) as sz from edge) select sz, count(*)  from check_it group by sz order by sz`